# Merging two IGrouping sets

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Suppose I have three users and I want to group them by their country. I would do this:

```
var users = new[]
{
    new User { Name = "Phil", Country = "UK" },
    new User { Name = "John", Country = "UK" },
    new User { Name = "Mike", Country = "USA" }
};

List<IGrouping<string, User>> groupedUsers
    = users.GroupBy(user => user.Country).ToList();
```

Now suppose my program gets three more users later on, so I group them too:

```
var moreUsers = new[]
{
    new User { Name = "Phoebe", Country = "AUS" },
    new User { Name = "Joan", Country = "UK" },
    new User { Name = "Mindy", Country = "USA" }
};

List<IGrouping<string, User>> moreGroupedUsers
    = moreUsers.GroupBy(user => user.Country).ToList();
```

I now have two seperate groupings, `groupedUsers` and `moreGroupedUsers`. How can I merge them into one whilst keeping the grouping valid?

Comment: merge sort is the immediate answer, you should just add one list to the other and sort again.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since the `IGrouping<,>` API does not provide a mutating interface, you would need to either:

- simply concatenate and re-group
- use a mutating container instead, maybe a `Dictionary<string, List<User>>` to which you can add

The first sounds simpler. It could be either:

```
var groupedUsers = groupedUsers.SelectMany(grp => grp)
        .Concat(moreUsers)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Country).ToList();
```

or:

```
var groupedUsers = users.Concat(moreUsers)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Country).ToList();
```

(if you still have `users` available)

The latter could be done with:

```
var mutable = users.GroupBy(user => user.Country).ToDictionary(
        grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.ToList());
```

then (to append):

```
foreach(var user in moreUsers) {
    List<User> list;
    if(!mutable.TryGetValue(user.Country, out list)) {
        mutable.Add(user.Country, list = new List<User>());
    }
    list.Add(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little late but this may help someone else that may want to avoid using the `Dictionary` class. Tho, this "solution" may cause performance problems for large collections and repetitive executions.

You just need to flatten the `users` group collection using the `IEnumerable.SelectMany` method, then concat the new elements to the flattened collection using the `Enumerable.Concat` method and finally regroup the elements using `IEnumerable.GroupBy` again.

Example:

```
var flattenedUsers = users.SelectMany(users => users);
var result = Enumerable.Concat(flattenedUsers, moreUsers).GroupBy(users.Country);
```